# PHP AJAX MySQL Insert Date from form is entering as: 12/31/1969

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, date

I have read several of the posts regarding the PHP date inserting into MySQL as 12/31/1969, but not seeing how to do that with AJAX.

My data/form flow:
- Use a datepicker to select date (Y-m-d)
- Submit form
- Passes through AJAX form in Header
- Is passed to a Processing page to INSERT into db.

```
*****MY AJAX FORM IN THE HEADER:*****
<script><!--BEGIN: AJAX PROCESS FORM-->

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#subformgeneral").click(function() {

// IF VISIBLE CHECKBOX IS CHECKED THEN = Y ELSE = N
if ($('#usersalevisible').is(":checked"))
{
var user_salevisible = 'Y';
} else {
var user_salevisible = 'N';
}
 // END CHECKBOX CONDITIONAL

var user_title = $("#title").val();
var user_startdate = $("#startdate").val();
var user_enddate = $("#enddate").val();
var user_restrictions = $("#salerestrictions").val();
var user_numsellers = $("#numsellers").val();


var user_form = $("#formid").val();
var user_saleid = $("#saleID").val();


$.post("usr-update-sale-process-2.php",{title:user_title,startdate:user_startdate,enddate:user_enddate,salerestrictions:user_restrictions,numsellers:user_numsellers,salevisible:user_salevisible,formid:user_form,saleID:user_saleid},function(data){

$("#result").html(data);

});

});

});

</script>
```

My DATE INPUT field from my form:

```
<!-- Start Date -->
<label class="control-label"  for="username">Start Date</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="startdate" placeholder="Start Date" class="input-xlarge  form-control" value="12/31/1969">
</div>


<input type="hidden" value="formgeneral" id="formid">
<input name="saleID" type="hidden" id="saleID" value="3262" />
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="subformgeneral" id="subformgeneral" value="Update General" />
```

I read an article from here regarding how to do `StrToTime` conversion, and that worked... on a regular form, but somehow it gets lost when passing through the AJAX form.

I do not have my Processing page code here, where I am at the moment, but it just receives my AJAX POST for STARTDATE, and INSERTS into MySQL.

I assume some sort of conversion has to take place on the Processing page (and I have tried, all I know to do), but not sure how, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the success error outcomes.

```
var user_title = $("#title").val();
var user_startdate = $("#startdate").val();
var user_enddate = $("#enddate").val();
var user_restrictions = $("#salerestrictions").val();
var user_numsellers = $("#numsellers").val();             

         $.ajax({
             url: "usr-update-sale-process-2.php",
             type: "POST",
             data: {
                 user_title: user_title,
                 user_startdate: user_startdate,
                 user_enddate: user_enddate,
                 user_restrictions: user_restrictions,
                 user_numsellers: user_numsellers 
             },
             cache: false,
             success: function(data) {
                 // Success message
             },
             error: function(data) {
                 // Fail message
             },
         });
```

Things to note: data the key is what the server will look for. Example: 
`$_POST['user_title']` will be equal to the `var user_title = $("#title").val();`

Also you can return true and false from the server which will be success and error respectively.